# How to decode PDF binary data to Postscript readable text

Tags: javascript, pdf, encoding, decoding, postscript

I'm currently searching for a way to extract the code (PostScript) behind a PDF just from its binary data.
I have an input of type file that has an onChange event handler attached. The event handler looks like this:

```js
const handleFileChange = (e) => {
  const [file] = e.target.files

  const reader = new FileReader()
  
  reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
    const buffer = reader.result
    const view = new DataView(buffer)
    
    const decoder = new TextDecoder("ascii")
    const text = decoder.decode(view)
  })
  
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}
```

This code produces text that looks like this `%PDF-1.3 %Äåòåë§ó ÐÄÆ 3 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 4573 >> stream xµ\ëŽÜ¶þÏ§ Ð¶Vwi‚ hìM`
The beginning is just fine, it's everything afterward is the issue - `%Äåòåë§ó ÐÄÆ` & `µ\ëŽÜ¶þÏ§ Ð¶Vwi‚ hìM`. It's illegible. I'm not sure if I just have the wrong [encoding](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#the-encoding) selected or what I'm setting out to do is all but impossible. Am I missing something here? If yes, what exactly?
I appreciate any and all help. Thank you!

(**resources are also welcomed**)

Comment: That's actually because the stream is compressed using FlateDecode. After 
`stream xµ\ëŽÜ¶þÏ§ Ð¶Vwi‚ hìM` can you please provide this full stream up until you encounter the text `endstream`

Comment: Indeed, and that Flate is used, can be determined from the **Filter** entry of the stream dictionary. But beware, that entry need not be a direct object like here (`/Filter /FlateDecode`), it may be indirect instead (`/Filter 8 0 R`). So in general you'll need to properly parse the PDF indirect object structure. Furthermore, **Filter** may contain multiple decoders which you have to apply one after the other...

Comment: Also, the 'code behind a PDF' isn't PostScript! You can use any of a number of tools to decompress a PDF file. MuPDF will do this for you with "mutool clean -d <input.pdf>" the resulting file out.pdf will be a decompressed version of the original. I'm certain other tools exist. However, the output will still be in PDF format, if you want to understand it, you'll need to read the PDF Reference Manual.